# Javascript Require

Tags: javascript, node.js

`include.js` file contain

```
var test = function(){
    console.log("log from included file");
};
```

`main.js` file contain

```
require('./include.js');
test();
```

when i tried to run `main.js` using `node main.js` command it shows

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'include.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\Nishada\test\main.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

what is the reason for this error ?

Comment: Use `require('./include.js')`.

Comment: you must export it: `module.exports = test;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error refers to a file not being found, make sure your file is in the same directory as main.js  and try:

include.js

```
module.exports = {
    test: function(){
        console.log("log from included file");
    }
}
```

main.js

```
var myInclude = require('include.js');
myInclude.test();
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to export the test function in order to use it in `main.js`

```
var test = function(){
    console.log("log from included file");
};

module.exports = test
```

And in `main.js` add `require` as follows

```
require('./include.js'); // assuming include.js is in same directory as main.js
```

If you do `require('include.js')` then node will search `include` in global packages

Comment: `module.exports = test` is not the only problem there

Comment: @MaxBumaye, it isn't anymore, the answer was incomplete

Answer (score 2):

You will have to give relative path of `include.js` while `require`.

If both are in same directory write it like bellow

```
var include = require('./include.js');
include.test();
```

and from `include.js` you can define them as function for `exports`

```
exports.test = function(){
    console.log("log from included file");
};
```

**Even Better**

export just one object having multiple functions from `include.js` instead of exporting each separate function.

Like bellow

`include.js`

```
exports.test = obj;
obj.func1 = function(){};
obj.func2 = function(){};
```

`main.js`

```
var test = require('./include.js').test;
test.func1();
test.func2();
```